# Show that $\overline{A}= \operatorname{int}(A)\cup \operatorname{fr} (A)$

Tags: general-topology

I've shown that $\operatorname{int}(A)\cup\operatorname{fr}(A)\subseteq \overline{A}$. But I need help with showing $\overline{A}\subseteq\operatorname{int}(A)\cup\operatorname{fr}(A)$

$\operatorname{int}(A)$ is the interior of the set $A$ and $\operatorname{fr}(A)=\overline{A}\cap\ (\overline{X\setminus A})$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $x\in\overline A$. If $x\notin A^\circ$, then $x\in\overline A\setminus A^\circ=\operatorname{fr}(A)$. Here, I used that fact that $X\setminus A^\circ=\overline{X\setminus A}$.

Comment: how do you show that $X\setminus int(A)\subseteq\overline{X\setminus A}$?

Comment: If $x\notin A^\circ$, then every neighborhood of $x$ intersects $X\setminus A$. Therefore, $x\in\overline{X\setminus A}$.

Comment: I still don't understand. Did you use another theorem?

Comment: @SidCaroline No. I used the definition of interior.

Comment: I don't get the logic behind "Therefore, $x\in\overline{X\setminus A}$". Actually the "therefore" is a consequence of a lemma which says $\overline{A}=\{x\in X\mid$ for every open set $U, x\in U \implies A\cap U\neq\emptyset\}$.

Comment: @SidCaroline For me, that's the *definition* of closure. That is, $x\in\overline M$ *means* that every neighbourhood interects $M$. How do you define closure?

Comment: I define closure of $A$ as the intersection of all closed supersets of $A$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63343/discussion-between-jose-carlos-santos-and-sid-caroline).

Answer (score 1):

If $x \in \overline{A}$ is such that $x \notin fr(A)$, then $x \notin \overline{X \setminus A}$, so there exists an open neighbourhood $U$ of $x$ such that $(X \setminus A) \cap U$ is empty. But this is just the same as saying that $U \subseteq A$ which implies $x \in int(A)$.

**Edit**: If $x \notin \overline{X \setminus A}$, then there exists a closed superset $C \supseteq X\setminus A$ not containing $x$. Then $U: =X \setminus C$ is an open subset of $A$ containing $x$.

Comment: I don't get why there exists an open neighbourhood $U$ of $x$ such that $(X\setminus A)\cap U$ is empty?

Comment: An element lies in the closure of a set if and only if the intersection of any open neighbourhood of that element with this set is nonempty. I edited my answer according to your definition of closure.

Answer (score 1):

$\text{int}A\subseteq A\subseteq\overline{A}$ and $\text{fr}(A)\subseteq\overline{A}$ so that also their union is a subset of $\overline{A}$.

Conversely if $x\in\overline{A}$ and $x\notin\text{int}{A}$ then every open set $U$ that contains $x$ as an element will **not** be a subset of $A$, i.e. will have a non-empty intersection with $X\setminus A$. That means exactly that $x\in\overline{X\setminus A}$.

Comment: But why "that means exactly $x\in \overline{X\setminus A}$?"

Comment: If $x\notin\overline{X\setminus A}$ then the complement of $\overline{X\setminus A}$ is open, contains $x$ and has empty intersection with  $\overline{X\setminus A}$. If conversely $x\in\overline{X\setminus A}$ then an open set $U$ that has empty intersection with $\overline{X\setminus A}$ cannot contain $x$ is element. This because the complement of $U$ is a closed set that contains $X\setminus A$ hence contains $\overline{X\setminus A}$ (so also contains $x$).

Answer (score 0):

**Using sequences :** Let $(x_n)$ a sequence of $A$ that converge to $x$. Then, for all $U\in \mathcal T$ that contain $x$, there is $N$ s.t. $x_n\in U$ for all $n\geq N$. In particular, all open set $U$ that contain $x$ is such that $U\cap A\neq \emptyset$. Now either $U\cap A^c\neq \emptyset$ for all open $U$ that contain $x$, and thus $x\in Fr(A)$, or there is an open set $U$ s.t. $U\cap A^c=\emptyset$ and thus $U\subset A$, and thus $x\in Int(A)$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $(x_n)$ a sequence of $A$ that converge to $x$. Then, for all $U\in \mathcal T$ that contain $x$, there is $N$ s.t. $x_n\in U$ for all $n\geq N$. In particular, all open set $U$ that contain $x$ is such that $U\cap A\neq \emptyset$. Now either $U\cap A^c\neq \emptyset$ for all open $U$ that contain $x$, and thus $x\in Fr(A)$, or there is an open set $U$ that contain $x$ s.t. $U\cap A^c=\emptyset$, and thus $U\subset A$. Therefore $x\in Int(A)$.